# UiAlertController disappears automatically, without user input

Tags: objective-c, uialertcontroller

I am attempting to present an warning UIAlertAction when a user has not enter text into a particular field. When the field is missing text and the user presses send, the alert appears for a moment then dismisses.

```
#pragma mark - Actions
- (IBAction)sendPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (_titleLabel.text.length == 0)
 {
    self.alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                                                   message:@"Please enter a title, it is required"
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                              [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
    [self.alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [self presentViewController:self.alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
else
{
}
if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(reportControllerDidPressSend:)]) {
    [_delegate reportControllerDidPressSend:self];
}
```

Comment: what is the isuse you are facing?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri The modal kept disappearing and it was caused by the errant else block that was pointed out below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware, that you have a empty else branch and an independent second if statement? I am quite sure, you want an `else if`-state meant instead

Also the test if delegate is nil isn't needed.

```
#pragma mark - Actions
- (IBAction)sendPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (_titleLabel.text.length == 0) {
       self.alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                                                   message:@"Please enter a title, it is required"
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

       UIAlertAction *defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                              [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }];
        [self.alert addAction:defaultAction];
        [self presentViewController:self.alert animated:YES completion:nil];

    } else if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(reportControllerDidPressSend:)])) {
        [_delegate reportControllerDidPressSend:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: The extra else was the stem of my problem @vikingosegundo thank you for pointing that out. Then I realized I didn't need the dismissViewController, seeing as I wanted to stay on the same page. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DalePalmer if this is correct answer, then accept it by ticking the answer.